# Using Elsa workflow with MySql database

Tags: elsa-workflows

I am trying to use Elsa workflow and to run it with database MySql, when application start and Elsa migrations run the following error happens

System.InvalidOperationException: 'A schema "Elsa" has been set for an object of type "AddColumnOperation" with the name of "DefinitionVersionId". MySQL does not support the EF Core concept of schemas. Any schema property of any "MigrationOperation" must be null. This behavior can be changed by setting the `SchemaBehavior` option in the `UseMySql` call.'

when i changed the schemabehavior another error happened, anyone faced this before?

Comment: What Elsa version are you using?

Comment: The last version

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, but the application starts with no issue. If you can share some steps to reproduce (probably easiest in the form of a simple project) then I'd be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dbContextBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString), mysql => mysql.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Elsa.Persistence.EntityFramework.MySql.MySqlElsaContextFactory).Assembly.FullName)
        .SchemaBehavior(MySqlSchemaBehavior.Ignore));
```

This ran the migrations without error for me.